# Configure ActiveMQ broker in grails

Tags: grails, jms, activemq-classic

Using Jms plugin for grails and add dependencies for ActiveMQ worked perfect. No problems.

Now I want to go beyond and perform some customization and fine tuning to make ActiveMQ behaves as I need, so I need to configure the broker instance.

e.g. I want to use JDBC storage.

How is possible to do that with grails and the vm embedded broker?

I've actually followed the reference documentation for the JMS grails plugin ... I add jms plugin and activemq dependencies and place this on resources:

```
jmsConnectionFactory(SingleConnectionFactory) {
    targetConnectionFactory = { ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf ->
        //brokerURL = 'vm://localhost'
        brokerURL = 'tcp://localhost:61616?jms.useAsyncSend=true'
    }
}
```

As I've said this is fine ... but I need more tuning here, so I've tried to go adding this in the resources, so I can access the broker to fine tuning:

```
/* Establish the broker */
amq.broker(useJmx: false, persistent: true) {
    amq.transportConnectors() {
        amq.transportConnector(uri: "tcp://localhost:61616")
    }
}

amqConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnectionFactory) {
    brokerURL = "vm://localhost"
}

jmsConnectionFactory(SingleConnectionFactory) {
    targetConnectionFactory = ref(amqConnectionFactory)
}
```

But I start to have dependency problems like:

```
2015-03-18 13:44:14 - spring.RuntimeSpringConfigUtilities [RuntimeConfiguration] Unable to load beans from resources.groovy
org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core] not found; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanNamespaceHandler
```

So I start adding dependencies:

```
    compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:5.7.0'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:4.1'
```

But still have problems:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/OrderComparator$OrderSourceProvider
```

At this point I get the feeling that I am doing something wrong since I see too much complexity.

Is there a best way to do this?

Comment: well, maybe the validator could have a point here.  what have you tried so far? show us some code.

Comment: Validator? ... what do you mean? ,,, i want to configure ActiveMQ to use MySQL persistence instead of KahaDB or filesystem

Comment: cfrick was talking about the SO question validator. However, looking through the source code for this plugin (https://github.com/domix/grails-activemq) It doesn't appear to have exposed any way to configure ActiveMQ. In order to further configure it in such a manner you are going to have to see what ActiveMQ supports (possibly a configuration file/settings on the classpath) or not use the plugin.

Comment: Sorry i probably does not explan well ... i am using jms plugin ... but not grails-activemq plugin.

Comment: Ok ... i've improved information. Thanks for the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to be able to configure ActiveMQ you'll need:

Dependencies:

```
    compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.7.0'
    compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:5.7.0'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:4.1'
```

Resources.groovy:

```
xmlns amq:"http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
```

...

```
/* Establish the broker */
amq.broker(useJmx: false, persistent: true) {
    amq.transportConnectors() {
        amq.transportConnector(uri: "tcp://localhost:61616")
    }
    //HERE YOU CAN CONFIGURE BROKER
}

amqConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnectionFactory) {
    brokerURL = "vm://localhost"
}

jmsConnectionFactory(SingleConnectionFactory) {
    targetConnectionFactory = ref(amqConnectionFactory)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The above answer of Rafael is very useful just a small change you need to do if you are working with **Grails 3.2.+** it took me few hrs to figure it out.

**Depedencies** (add them in build.gradle)

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:jms:2.0.0.RC2'
compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.7.0'
compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:5.14.5'
compile 'org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:4.1'
```

**Resources.groovy** (should look something like)

```
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
import org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory

beans = {
    ....
    xmlns amq:"http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
    amq.broker(useJmx: false, persistent: true) {
    amq.transportConnectors() {
        amq.'transportConnector'(uri: "tcp://localhost:61616")
        // optional if you want to do something with mqtt
        amq.'transportConnector'(uri:'mqtt://0.0.0.0:61612')
        }
    }

    jmsConnectionFactory(SingleConnectionFactory) {
        targetConnectionFactory = { ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf ->
            brokerURL = 'vm://localhost'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```